# Why is the conditional (ternary) operator evaluated in a logical AND when the lhs is false

Tags: java, logic, conditional-operator, short-circuiting

```
return super.isAvailable() && expander != null 
    && rightNotLeft ? !expander.isExpandedRight() : expander.isExpandedRight();
```

My problem was that when expander was null I was getting a null pointer exception. But I didn't think that this should happen since expander!=null is being evaluated to false and since ANDs are being used the entire expression should short circuit and return false.

```
return super.isAvailable() && expander != null 
    && (rightNotLeft ? !expander.isExpandedRight() : expander.isExpandedRight());
```

The above code (adding the parentheses) solved the problem. However this does not make sense to me as no matter what happens in the conditional operator there is no way to return true so shouldn't it short circuit?

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: the fact that adding parentheses fixed the problem should reveal the answer - `&&` binds tighter than `? :`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to [operator precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). Your condition without explicit parentheses is actually evaluated like

```
return (super.isAvailable() && expander != null 
    && rightNotLeft) ? !expander.isExpandedRight() : expander.isExpandedRight();
```

Comment: huh okay, I just never thought that the ternary term would ever be broken up, I always thought of it as a single expression that would be evaluated as a whole not as part of the rest. Thanks for helping to improve my understanding.